# how to know data came from keyentry or a device

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a field which takes values from both key entry or from a scanner.

I want to differentiate the data coming from scanner or key entry. If its from scanner I want to add scanner as prefix else nothing.

I am using Java, Spring form tags, Jsp.

How can I get the info if its comiing from scanner or key entry?

what I found from research is to get the time took to enter the data. But, how can I do it?

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not add a checkbox that either only the device or only the people would fill?

Comment: Dont want to add any more fields or checkbox for users..if user starts a scan he will be doing that for 100 or more and he can change to key entry any time..

Comment: Then instead of a checkbox, some sort of global toggle button? "Start manual entry", "Stop manual entry". Tracking time to enter data would be feasible, but it'd require adding a bunch of Javascript that's much more complex than a single boolean input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event - and set a timer to see how fast the user is typing.
However, in my experience, every scanner I have used limits the keystroke speed to an almost "human" speed so the system is probably not 100% reliable - maybe you should look into consistency of speed more than actual speed.